# Menu Shortcut with two letters Ctrl+F+A

Tags: menu, wxpython

I know is possible to have a menu shortcut like Ctrl+Shift+F but I do not find a way to make something like Ctrl+F+A work. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so.
If you look at the ´wx.AcceleratorEntry` you'll find:

> AcceleratorEntry(flags=0, keyCode=0, cmd=0, item=None)

> flags (int) – A combination of the wx.AcceleratorEntryFlags values, which indicates which modifier keys are held down.

> keyCode (int) – The keycode to be detected. See wx.KeyCode for a full list of keycodes.

> cmd (int) – The menu or control command identifier (ID).

> item (wx.MenuItem) – The menu item associated with this accelerator.

So in effect, you want to have multiple `keyCode`'s.
Given that it's a single `int` rather than a series of flags that accept bitwise operations, I think your cunning plan is doomed.